# Problems inserting utf8 data to PostgreSQL with Python

Tags: python, windows, postgresql, encoding, utf-8

I am reading scandinavian language websites with a web-crawler - and wish to insert them into my PostgreSQL database.

Originally I tried to encode my PSQL DB as utf-8, then manually tried to insert the characters that would be of a problem like this:

`Insert into name (surname) VALUES ('Børre');`

This was done in the windows PSQL shell.

This gave me the following error: ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x9b. So after doing some googling I changed the client encoding to latin1. Now that statement was successfull. The server encoding is still utf8.

When I do the same insert through my python script the name appears in my database as B°rre. If I change back the encoding of client to utf8, I also get entries with wrong special characters.

My python script is utf8 encoded, but prints the name correct.

Insert statement:

```
con = psycopg2.connect(*database details*)

print("Opened database successfully")

cur = con.cursor()

#INSERT NAME

query = "INSERT INTO name (surname) VALUES (%s) RETURNING id"

data = ('børre')

cur.execute(query,data)
```

As previously stated, print(personObject.surname) gives 'Børre'

If I try the following:

```
query = "INSERT INTO name (surname) VALUES (%s) RETURNING id"

data = ('børre'.encode('utf-8'))

cur.execute(query,data)
```

I get the following in my database:

\x62c383c2b8727265

Comment: Which version of Python?

Comment: Can you post your stack trace ?

Comment: Why don't you use UTF-8 encoding? Today, there exists no reason not to use it.

Comment: Python version is  3.x. The reason why I changed from utf-8 is stated in the start of the question. I will update the question with stack trace asap.

Comment: The stack trace does not output anything, I get no error in python. @LaurentLAPORTE

Comment: Where did you do this `INSERT` in the first place? You should use a database shell, that supports UTF8 and do **not** change the encoding of your database.

Comment: This was done in a database shell. I get the same encoding issues when I insert via python.

Answer (score 1):

psycopg2 doesn't understand postgresql queries it just converts the arguments given into their postgresql representation

if you give it an array of bytes to will convert it to a postgresql BYTEA literal,

`data = ('børre'.encode('utf-8'))` gets you a `bytes`.

so, don't do that, use a `string`.

The code fragment you have at the top should work.

In the error I see `ø` encoded as hex `c383c2b8`, that hex translates to UTF8 as two characters`Ã` and `¸`.  It looks to me like python thinks your script is not wtitten is UTF8, but instead some other codepage.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Any suggestion on how I will get 'børre' to be 'børre' in the PSQL database as well?

Answer (score 0):

using ***client_encoding*** key words
eg: conn=psycopg2.connect("dbname='foo' user='dbuser' password='mypass' ***client_encoding='utf8'***")